# Adobe PDF File Validation Programmatically, ideally via C#

Tags: pdf

I have a lot of pdfs that are copied from one server to another server. Due to connection issue, a few get corrupted without error warning. However, it says the file is not readable when it is opened in Acrobat Reader. I want to find out if there is API that I can test it whether it is a valid pdf to open, ideally in C#

I wonder if ExpertPDF can help, which contains APIs.

[ExpertPDF HtmlToPdf Converter](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/Features.aspx)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if a PDF is valid I would take a look at [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/). You can try opening the file using a `PdfReader` (any overload except one that takes a `RandomAccessFileOrArray` which I don't think parses the entire file immediately).

```
PdfReader r = new PdfReader("c:\\File.pdf");
```

But do you have control over this server-to-server transfer process? Files shouldn't be corrupting in the first place. Maybe you've got an FTP ASCII/BINARY problem? Is the file size changing? Can you perform a pre and post checksum, even something simple like MD5? Fix the problem instead of cleaning up when it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **VERIFY** to ON before running xcopy or robocopy to ensure the file integrity.

Otherwise you can run a command line utility such as [PDFLEO](http://mdn.morovia.com/manuals/pdfleo-1/PDF-Overview.php#Querying-Document-Information) to dump the metadata. If it reports an error the file is likely damaged.